# Regex Error and Improvement Driving Licence Data Extraction

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-re

I am trying to extract the Name, License No., Date Of Issue and Validity from an Image I processed using Pytesseract. I am quite a lot confused with regex but still went through few documentations and codes over the web.

I got till here:

```
import pytesseract
import cv2
import re

import cv2

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import datetime

from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def driver_license(filename):  
    """
    This function will handle the core OCR processing of images.
    """
    
    i = cv2.imread(filename)
    newdata=pytesseract.image_to_osd(i)
    angle = re.search('(?<=Rotate: )\d+', newdata).group(0)
    angle = int(angle)
    i = Image.open(filename)
    if angle != 0:
       #with Image.open("ro2.jpg") as i:
        rot_angle = 360 - angle
        i = i.rotate(rot_angle, expand="True")
        i.save(filename)
    
    i = cv2.imread(filename)
    # Convert to gray
    i = cv2.cvtColor(i, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Apply dilation and erosion to remove some noise
    kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
    i = cv2.dilate(i, kernel, iterations=1)
    i = cv2.erode(i, kernel, iterations=1)
    
    txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(i)
    print(txt)
        
    text = []
    data = {
        'firstName': None,
        'lastName': None,
        'age': None,
        'documentNumber': None
    }
    
    c = 0
    print(txt)
    
    #Splitting lines
    lines = txt.split('\n')
    
    for lin in lines:
        c = c + 1
        s = lin.strip()
        s = s.replace('\n','')
        if s:
            s = s.rstrip()
            s = s.lstrip()
            text.append(s)

            try:
                if re.match(r".*Name|.*name|.*NAME", s):           
                    name = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]+', ' ', s)
                    name = name.replace('Name', '')
                    name = name.replace('name', '')
                    name = name.replace('NAME', '')
                    name = name.replace(':', '')
                    name = name.rstrip()
                    name = name.lstrip()
                    nmlt = name.split(" ")
                    data['firstName'] = " ".join(nmlt[:len(nmlt)-1])
                    data['lastName'] = nmlt[-1]
                if re.search(r"[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]-\d{13}", s):
                    data['documentNumber'] = re.search(r'[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]-\d{13}', s)
                    data['documentNumber'] = data['documentNumber'].group().replace('-', '')
                    if not data['firstName']:
                        name = lines[c]           
                        name = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]+', ' ', name)
                        name = name.rstrip()
                        name = name.lstrip()
                        nmlt = name.split(" ")
                        data['firstName'] = " ".join(nmlt[:len(nmlt)-1])
                        data['lastName'] = nmlt[-1]
                if re.search(r"[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\d{2} \d{11}", s):
                    data['documentNumber'] = re.search(r'[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\d{2} \d{11}', s)
                    data['documentNumber'] = data['documentNumber'].group().replace(' ', '')
                    if not data['firstName']:
                        name = lines[c]           
                        name = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]+', ' ', name)
                        name = name.rstrip()
                        name = name.lstrip()
                        nmlt = name.split(" ")
                        data['firstName'] = " ".join(nmlt[:len(nmlt)-1])
                        data['lastName'] = nmlt[-1]
                if re.match(r".*DOB|.*dob|.*Dob", s):         
                    yob = re.sub('[^0-9]+', ' ', s)
                    yob = re.search(r'\d\d\d\d', yob)
                    data['age'] = datetime.datetime.now().year - int(yob.group())
            except:
                pass

    print(data)
```

I need to extract the Validity and Issue Date as well. But not getting anywhere near it. Also, I have seen using regex shortens the code like a lot so is there any better optimal way for it?

My input data is a string somewhat like this:

```
Transport Department Government of NCT of Delhi
Licence to Drive Vehicles Throughout India

Licence No. : DL-0820100052000 (P) R
N : PARMINDER PAL SINGH GILL

: SHRI DARSHAN SINGH GILL

DOB: 10/05/1966 BG: U
Address :

104 SHARDA APPTT WEST ENCLAVE
PITAMPURA DELHI 110034

  

Auth to Drive Date of Issue
M.CYL. 24/02/2010
LMV-NT 24/02/2010

(Holder's Sig natu re)

Issue Date : 20/05/2016
Validity(NT) : 19/05/2021 : c
Validity(T) : NA Issuing Authority
InvCarrNo : NA NWZ-I, WAZIRPUR
```

Or like this:

```
in

Transport Department Government of NCT of Delhi
Licence to Drive Vehicles Throughout India

2

   
    
   

Licence No. : DL-0320170595326 () WN
Name : AZAZ AHAMADSIDDIQUIE
s/w/D : SALAHUDDIN ALI
____... DOB: 26/12/1992 BG: O+
\ \ Address:
—.~J ~—; ROO NO-25 AMK BOYS HOSTEL, J.
— NAGAR, DELHI 110025
Auth to Drive Date of Issue
M.CYL. 12/12/2017
4 wt 4
Iseue Date: 12/12/2017 a
falidity(NT) < 2037
Validity(T) +: NA /
Inv CarrNo : NA te sntian sana
```

Note: In the second example you wouldn't get the validity, will optimise the OCR for later. Any proper guide which can help me with regex which is a bit simpler would be good.

Comment: In your input which one is the name?

Comment: N : PARMINDER PAL SINGH GILL in example 1
AZAZ AHAMADSIDDIQUIE in example 2

Comment: And there you have two validity (in the first example) which one do you want to get?

Comment: First one only required. I can refer to that later if later changes required.

Comment: In the second example "Iseue Date" is a type?

Comment: It should be Issue Date: 12/12/2017 but tesseract has a few errors while reading from images. So, regex should manage from similar typos.

Comment: Unless there is an explicit requirement to match fuzzy versions of `Issue`, etc., you do not need the PyPi regex library, it can be done with `re` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this pattern: `(?<=KEY\s*:\s*)\b[^\n]+` and replace KEY with one of the issues of the date, License No. and others.
Also for this pattern, you need to use [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) library.

Code:

```
import regex

text1 = """
Transport Department Government of NCT of Delhi
Licence to Drive Vehicles Throughout India

Licence No. : DL-0820100052000 (P) R
N : PARMINDER PAL SINGH GILL

: SHRI DARSHAN SINGH GILL

DOB: 10/05/1966 BG: U
Address :

104 SHARDA APPTT WEST ENCLAVE
PITAMPURA DELHI 110034



Auth to Drive Date of Issue
M.CYL. 24/02/2010
LMV-NT 24/02/2010

(Holder's Sig natu re)

Issue Date : 20/05/2016
Validity(NT) : 19/05/2021 : c
Validity(T) : NA Issuing Authority
InvCarrNo : NA NWZ-I, WAZIRPUR
"""

for key in ('Issue Date', 'Licence No\.', 'N', 'Validity\(NT\)'):
    print(regex.findall(fr"(?<={key}\s*:\s*)\b[^\n]+", text1, regex.IGNORECASE))
```

Output:

```
['20/05/2016']
['DL-0820100052000 (P) R']
['PARMINDER PAL SINGH GILL']
['19/05/2021 : c']
```

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean by "with one of the issues of the date, License No. and others" ? You mean to put Licence No. and others as a string and pass it as KEY?

Comment: Yes, look at the code. I did what I mean.

Comment: Yeah got it. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `re` with a single regex based on alternation that will capture your keys and values:

```py
import re
text = "Transport Department Government of NCT of Delhi\nLicence to Drive Vehicles Throughout India\n\nLicence No. : DL-0820100052000 (P) R\nN : PARMINDER PAL SINGH GILL\n\n: SHRI DARSHAN SINGH GILL\n\nDOB: 10/05/1966 BG: U\nAddress :\n\n104 SHARDA APPTT WEST ENCLAVE\nPITAMPURA DELHI 110034\n\n\n\nAuth to Drive Date of Issue\nM.CYL. 24/02/2010\nLMV-NT 24/02/2010\n\n(Holder's Sig natu re)\n\nIssue Date : 20/05/2016\nValidity(NT) : 19/05/2021 : c\nValidity(T) : NA Issuing Authority\nInvCarrNo : NA NWZ-I, WAZIRPUR"
search_phrases = ['Issue Date', 'Licence No.', 'N', 'Validity(NT)']
reg = r"\b({})\s*:\W*(.+)".format( "|".join(sorted(map(re.escape, search_phrases), key=len, reverse=True)) )
print(re.findall(reg, text, re.IGNORECASE))
```

Output of this short [online Python demo](https://ideone.com/CIv6Aw):

```py
[('Licence No.', 'DL-0820100052000 (P) R'), ('N', 'PARMINDER PAL SINGH GILL'), ('Issue Date', '20/05/2016'), ('Validity(NT)', '19/05/2021 : c')]
```

The regex is

```py
\b(Validity\(NT\)|Licence\ No\.|Issue\ Date|N)\s*:\W*(.+)
```

See [its online demo](https://regex101.com/r/KoBnXT/1/).

*Details*:

- `map(re.escape, search_phrases)` - escapes all special chars in your search phrases to be used as literal texts in  a regex (else, `.` will match any chars, `?` won't match a `?` char, etc.)
- `sorted(..., key=len, reverse=True)` - sorts the search phrases by length in descending order (to get longer matches first)
- `"|".join(...)` - creates an alternation pattern, `a|b|c|...`
- `r"\b({})\s*:\W*(.+)".format( ... )` - creates the final regex.

*Regex details*

- `\b` - a word boundary (**NOTE**: replace with `(?m)^` if your matches occur at the beginning of a line)
- `(Validity\(NT\)|Licence\ No\.|Issue\ Date|N)` - Group 1: one of the search phrases
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `:` - a colon
- `\W*` - zero or more non-word chars
- `(.+)` - (capturing) Group 2:  one or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.